# Really slow copying a file to a win 8.1 pc over LAN, no other network issues

Tags: windows, networking, connection

I have a windows 8.1 pc thats being running fine for ages. Suddenly it's unable to play videos from a network share. Digging into it I've found the following:

Copying a file from any of the three other machines on my LAN won't go any faster than 300kb/s. This includes copying a file from the machine, or pushing the file to the machine via a network share.

Copying a file to the machine from any other source on the lan will max the connection out (around 90MB/s). Again this includes both pulling a file from the machine, or pulling the file from a server.

Downloading a file from the internet works totally fine (I can get 50mb/s down, 15mb up - maxing my connection). I also downloaded windows 8.1 again from msdn so I can restore the machine, again without issue maxing my speed (and way quicker than the 300kb/s I can get from other machines on the lan).

To try and resolve this I have turned the firewall off, rebooted the machine, applied the latest patches, checked I have the latest patches on the network ports and I've "refreshed" the pc.

I can't spot anything obvious in the event log either.

I've also started pulling a file from the machine (getting 90MB/s) at the same time I pushed a file to the machine and both transfers dropped to around 1kb/s!

Heres an image showing some diagnostics that might help

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Ta

Comment: Download sysinternals's tcpview from Microsft.Run the initialize tcpview and commence with copying files over the smb share.Post the screenshot so that we can see what's going.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the client to a different place in the house has "resolved" the issue. I'll try switch network ports/cables etc and see if I can track it down. Thanks all!